# Magento 2 : How to convert class object to string using observer?

Tags: event-observer, xml, magento2.3.0

I am getting error during to save order data to xml format using observer..

> Recoverable Error: Object of class
>   Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item\Interceptor could not be converted to
>   string in

```
 namespace XYZ\Checkout\Observer;

 use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Simplexml\Element as SimpleXMLElement;


  class Afterplaceorder implements ObserverInterface
   {     
     protected $_request;
     protected $_layout;
     protected $_objectManager;
     protected $_resource;
     protected $dir;
     protected $jsonHelper;
     protected $timezone;
     protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;
     protected $_io;
     protected $_cartExtension;


/**
* @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
*/
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $io,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartExtension $cartExtension
){
    $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
    $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
    $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->_dir = $dir;
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    $this->timezone = $timezone;
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->_io = $io;
    $this->_cartExtension = $cartExtension;
}


/**
* @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
* @return void
*/
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{   
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/orderdata.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $order   = $observer->getData('order');
    $orderId = $order->getId();
    $QuoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
    $CustomerId = $order->getCustomerId();

    $logger->info(print_r($order->getIncrementId(),true));

    $quote = $observer->getQuote();

    try{        

        $LocalInstitute     = $quote->getLocalInstitute();
        $SocietyInstitute   = $quote->getLocalSociety();
        $AuthStatus         = $quote->getAuthStatus();
        $SentApi            = 1;
        $response           = 0;
        $NavOrderId         = " ";

        if($LocalInstitute):    
            $order->setLocalInstitute($LocalInstitute)->setLocalSociety($SocietyInstitute)->setAuthStatus($AuthStatus)->setApiSentFromMagento($SentApi)->setApiResponseFromNav($response)->setApiResponseNavOrderId($NavOrderId);
            $order->save();
        endif;  

        $customerDetails = array();             
        $orderItemsxml   = array();

        foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $orderItem) 
            {
              $orderItemsxml[] = $orderItem;                
            }

            $orderDeatails['orderItems']      = $orderItemsxml;     
            $orderDeatails['billingAddress']  =     $order->getBillingAddress()->getData();
            $orderDeatails['shippingAddress'] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();

                // function defination to convert array to xml
                function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
                    foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
                        if( is_numeric($key) ){
                            $key = 'item'.$key; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
                        }
                        if( is_array($value) ) {
                            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
                            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
                        } else {
                            $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
                        }
                     }
                }


                $data = array('total_stud' => 500);
                // creating object of SimpleXMLElement
                $xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><order></order>');

                //$OrderCollection = array_merge($orderDeatails,$customerDetails);
                // function call to convert array to xml
                array_to_xml($orderDeatails,$xml_data);
                //saving generated xml file;
                if ( ! file_exists($this->_dir->getPath('var').'/api/order')) {
                    $this->_io->mkdir($this->_dir->getPath('var').'/api/order', 0775); 
                }
                $result = $xml_data->asXML($this->_dir->getRoot().'/var/api/order/order_'.$order->getIncrementId().'.xml');

        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $logger->info(print_r('error-> '.$e->getMessage(),true));
        }

        return; 
   }
 }
```

I didn't find what is wrong with my code.

Please anyone can resolve this..

Answer (score 4):

I fond a solution for it

You can use jsonEncode and Decode to resolve the issue.

$this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($order->getItemsCollection()));

Here is the full code

```
class Afterplaceorder implements ObserverInterface
{    
   protected $_Logs;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
){
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
}

public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{   
    $order   = $observer->getData('order');

    try{                    
            $orderDeatails['orderItems']      = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($order->getItemsCollection()));

        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $logger->info(print_r('error-> '.$e->getMessage(),true));
        }

        return;

}
```

}

Its working well for me.

hope it will help others to resolve these kind of issues.

Thanks! Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that one of the elements of sub elements of `orderDeatails` is the actual order object and when generating the xml you handle the cases where the element is numerical or array. Otherwise you treat it as a sting. And for the order object your script tries to convert it to string.
it could be the `$orderItem` elements. I think they contain a reference to the order object.